# Variable name and restrict operators in math.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I'm using [math.js](http://mathjs.org/) to validate mathematical equations against missing closing parentheses or duplicate operators, etc so the following will be considered as an incorrect equation:

```
9 + ((5 * 6)//12
```

This works fine. However what I'm trying to do is that allow a variable name in the equation, like this:

```
9 + (variableName * 6) / 12
```

The variable name should also be the same. So, the validator will need to know that it's OK if it finds "variableName" in the expression.

Also I want to restrict the allowed equation operators to only the following:

```
()-+/*
```

I've tried to find the answers of those questions in the documentation but with no luck.

Is anybody aware of how this is being done in math.js?

Comment: You don't need to use `math.js` to evaluate such expressions as `9 + (variableName * 6) / 12`

Comment: @hindmost: Care to provide an alternative? OP isn't trying to calculate the result. He's validating the expression.

Comment: Well, how are you going to validate the input then? To make sure that there are no not closed parentheses or there are duplicated operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do with math.js is parse an expression into a node tree:

```
var tree = math.parse('9 + (variableName * 6) / 12');
```

With the current version of math.js you can analyse the tree using the function `find` (undocumented, see [explanation here](https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/blob/master/lib/expression/node/Node.js#L77-L95)). The next version of math.js will have more extensive (and documented) support in the form of the functions `traverse` and `transform`, which allow you to easily loop over all nodes in the tree and do something.

With these functions you can for example find all SymbolNodes and check whether they are allowed, and find all OperatorNodes and check whether they are allowed. I created a jsbin for you to demonstrate how you can analyse a parsed expression:

http://jsbin.com/duduru/1/edit?html,output

Alternatively, you could generate your own parser using [PEG.js](http://pegjs.majda.cz/) or [Jison](http://zaach.github.io/jison/).

EDIT: The latest version of math.js now officially supports operations on expression trees, see documentation: http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/expression_trees.html

Comment: Thanks for your help, this really helps! However the following expression passes as valid while it's not a valid math expression: var expression = '9 ++++-- + 12';

Comment: Well, it is valid though not very useful in practice: a series of unary pluses and minuses (`9 + -12` and `9 - -12` still makes sense). If you don't want to allow this, you could add another test for that...